# Microsoft graph delta api for Documents of a specific folder?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I want to use graph delta API to track changes in a specific folder of my drive.

Documentation provides an example of using delta API on the root drive.

When I am trying to use the same API to get my documents from "Attachments" folder it is giving an error.

**My Request API**: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userid/drive/root/delta:/Attachments:/children

**Error response**:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "The request URI is not valid. The segment 'delta' must be the last segment in the URI because it is one of the following: $ref, $batch, $count, $value, $metadata, a named media resource, an action, a noncomposable function, an action import, a noncomposable function import, an operation with void return type, or an operation import with void return type.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d98d91f1-f131-4d76-89bd-4c980b13f92d",
            "date": "2017-10-11T12:55:09"
        }
    }
}
```

what is the mistake in this API call?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for the delta query - 
In OneDrive for Business and SharePoint, delta is only supported on the root folder, not on other folders within a drive.

Refer - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_delta

Comment: This is correct, but I'll also call out that if it did work you'd want to hit a URL that looks like `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userid/drive/root:/Attachments:/delta`